# Create a color palette for points on a texture in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There are many points with different coordinates on X, Y. But on the Z axis, the deviation of the points is small. I would like to create a color palette of distribution fields for values by Z, for example, the link

https://www.liraland.ru/images/journal/1491/004.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read here on how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your post accordingly

Comment: you can try raycast to get the color pixel it hit using Texture Coordinate in unity

Sorry, I'm away from my computer so I cant provide u with any samples. but its a starting point.